# How to call a function after an animation ends?

Tags: c++, qt

So I've recently started dabbling a bit with the Qt animation framework and I'd say everything goes pretty well, however now I'd like to make it so that a function gets called after an animation finishes, is this possible?

I've already tried executing the function after the animation starts, however this doesn't seem to work (I presume because Qt animations are ran on a separate thread)

The way I've tried this is very simply like this:

```
AnimIn->setDuration(500);
AnimIn->setStartValue(0.f);
AnimIn->setEndValue(1.f);
AnimIn->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InCubic);
AnimIn->start();
MyFunction();
```

I've tried looking through the Qt documentation but to no avail, seeing that pretty much everything about animation and Qt is in QML which I don't use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to listen to the `finished()` signal from your animation. Here's how you'd connect the signal:

`QObject::connect(AnimIn, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, &YourClass::OnAnimFinished);`

where OnAnimFinished() is obviously a slot in your current class. When the animation finishes, the signal will be emitted and the slot will be invoked. Then in the body of the `OnAnimFinished()` function you can call `MyFunction()`.